# Passing values from one jsp to another jsp using Href

Tags: jsp

> **FirstPage.jsp**

`<a href="common.jsp?param=<%l.get(k).parentname%>">`

> **Common.jsp**

```
<%
    String attr = request.getAttribute("param");
    out.print(attr);
%>
```

Since url print a **common.jsp?param=Arts**

but `attr` return a null value. I'm getting null values while I pass value using href.

I'm using Spring and apache server.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing query parameter. it should be get using `request.getParameter` as:

```
request.getParameter("param")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't miss the equals caracter (=) when you are setting a Java object value to Javascript or HTML objects references.

Example:

FirstPage.jsp

```
<a href="common.jsp?param=<%=l.get(k).parentname%>">
```

Common.jsp

```
<%String attr = request.getParameter("param");
  System.out.println(attr);%>
```

I hope this helps you!

Regards,
Renan